# Get data passed into Angular2 Component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a Component with template:

```
<some-component>
  <div>some stuff </div>
</some-component>
```

How can I get data passed into Component and push them into some place in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can use `<ng-content></ng-content>` for the same.

in `some-component` use ng-content like this :-

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-component',
    template: `left <ng-content></ng-content> right`,
})
class SomeComponent {}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<some-component>INSERTED</some-component>`,
    directives: [some-component],
})
class MyApp {}
```

Basically, `<ng-content></ng-content>` is like transclude from Angular 1.

you can also use more than one `ng-content` in a single component by using named ng-content
like this :-

```
<child-select>
    <section>Section Content</section>
    <div class="class-select">
      div with .class-select
    </div>
    <footer>Footer Content</footer>
    <header>Header Content</header>
  </child-select>
```

in order to use this in the `child-select` component you have to specify in the template like this:-

```
    <div style="border: 2px solid red; padding: 1rem; margin: 2px;">
        <h4>Child Component with Select</h4>
        <div style="border: 2px solid orange; padding: 1rem; margin: 2px">
          <ng-content select="header"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 2px solid green; padding: 1rem; margin: 2px">
          <ng-content select="section"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 2px solid pink; padding: 1rem; margin: 2px">
          <ng-content select=".class-select"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 2px solid purple; padding: 1rem; margin: 2px">
          <ng-content select="footer"></ng-content>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is working plnker <kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AiDiNl8SrSKIwDUYWl50?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Is there any way to know whether the data is transferred to?

Comment: sorry dont get you what you want to say ?

Comment: Yeah, my English is bad)

How could Component know that someone push data insert?

Comment: Its the syntax of angular2 ? what do you mean by ` How could Component know that someone push data insert?`

Comment: Hmmm...
Is there way to know is ng-content empty or not?

Comment: may be but i dont have any idea about this.